smart switch wiring with no neutral, but the switch is giving me issues
So I have a smart switch I wanted to pop in to my house. 3 gang. I do not have neutral at the switch, so i put a capacitor over live and neutral (that was supplied with the switch) at the first light. I then wired live to live, first switch to first and so on. But in order for light 2 and 3 to work, light 1 has to be on. If I switch off light 1, they all go off. My assumption is that I need a capacitor at each light, or something is up with the wiring in my house. Does anyone have a solution to this issue? One person at work said i should just run a neutral to the switch, but I want to know if there is a fix before having to do that, as I want to do this throughout my house.

Please post a photo

Thanks Rohit, I'll certainly post a photo. I'll take some this evening and pop them on here

There are 2 proper solutions:

Find a smart switch that doesn't require neutral
Run a neutral to your switch location. As the neutral needs to follow the exact same route as the live and/or switched-live, this will involve re-doing the wiring if there currently is a switch loop created with /2 Romex.


Hi Bart. Thanks for answering. I just want to see that I understand you correctly.
The switch I bought came with a capacitor, and showed an alternate wiring if no neutral is in the box where the switch is. So is this not considered a No Neutral type switch? Is neutral wiring paramount? ie, if neutral going to light 1 is not same as light 2 or 3. I'm at my wits end, as I think option 2 is looking to be the only option here unless someone has a small change that can be made to fix it. like a capacitor at each light? I don't know.

@RobertBarnsley, can you update the question with this information and also information about the make/model of the smart switch? From your comment it looks like you may already have a switch that doesn't require neutral.

Yes, Bart I'll take photo of the unit, how I have wired it up and get as much detail as I can through when I get home this evening.

Before I go home and find out, I want to put down here quick what has dawned on me as I was explaining it to someone at work.... and let's see if it is the case, in which case I am a proper fool. I think I have put Live into L1 and L1 wire into Live. This seems the most plausible reason I have this issue. I will update you tomorrow.
